# Is it possible to create Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap from System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Tags: c#, opencv, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am writing an application in Avalonia and using OpenCvSharp to get frames from the camera. This worked with WPF - there I just called

```
Image.Source = Mat.ToBitmapSource();
```

but this doesn't work in Avalonia, because there is a different type of *Image* control, and a different type of its *Source* property.

I tried doing this via a *MemoryStream*, but then the *Bitmap* constructor crashes with an *ArgumentNullException* (although the stream is not null).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this question? I’m exploring the same thing right now since System.Drawing was added to .NET core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, as soon as I asked you that, I found a solution. Load the image into memory and then call it back.

I was getting the same type of error but that was fixed after I implemented the using statement.

```
//Place this in your class to create a class variable and create the System.Drawing.Bitmap Bitmap 
private System.Drawing.Bitmap irBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(256, 192, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
```

```
//Add this using statement to the function you're converting inside of 
//to convert the System.Drawing.Bitmap to Avalonia compatible image for view/viewmodel

using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                irBitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
                memory.Position = 0;

                //AvIrBitmap is our new Avalonia compatible image. You can pass this to your view
                Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap AvIrBitmap = new Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap(memory);
             }
```

Let me know if you have questions or how to specifically tie this into your app. There wasn't a lot of code provided earlier so I didn't have any idea what to name variables for your specific use case.

Comment: Perfectly! This code works. Thank you very much, ryano!