# Why is creating a System.Drawing.Bitmap from a byte[] - then storing the Bitmap in Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap - resulting in a black image?

Tags: image, data-conversion, avaloniaui

i am using some code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63391133/is-it-possible-to-create-avalonia-media-imaging-bitmap-from-system-drawing-bitma) thread to store byte[] data as System.Drawing.Bitmap, to then store it as Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap. Using this Avalonia Bitmap in an image control in my avalonia app only shows a black image.

```
    private System.Drawing.Bitmap? _regularBitmap = new (1920, 1080, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565);

    public void DecodeAndUpdateBitmap(byte[] imageData)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            _regularBitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            ms.Position = 0;

            _tempImage = new Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap(ms);
        }
    }
```

The byte[] passed in as a method parameter, which used for the memory stream definitely has data stored in it as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

So my guess is, the way i a creating to System.Drawing.Bitmap to be used as a Avalonia.Media.Imaging.Bitmap is causing this issue.

Does anyone know of a better way to do what i am trying to achieve or maybe knows what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [WriteableBitmap](https://reference.avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Media.Imaging/WriteableBitmap/).

```cs
var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap( 
  new PixelSize(1920, 1080), 
  new Vector(96, 96), 
  PixelFormat.Bgra8888, 
  AlphaFormat.Premul); 
  
using (var frameBuffer = bitmap.Lock()) 
{ 
  Marshal.Copy(imageData, 0, frameBuffer.Address, imageData.Length); 
}

_tempImage = bitmap;
```

Comment: Hi, using your above code, i no longer get a black image, but now it is just a small strip of random colered noise. Would i need to use a different pixel format? The source of the image data is a Logitech Webcam C930e, the image is captured using FlashCap library.

Comment: I tried different pixel and alpha formats, only to get the same result. The source of the image data is a Logitech Webcam C930e, the image is captured using FlashCap library. Does this have to do with the Avalonia Bitmap, or is this a problem with the captured image data? I don't know how to test if the image data is corrupted.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the out of FlashCap but a quick search and I found they have an Avalonia demo...  https://github.com/kekyo/FlashCap/tree/main/samples/FlashCap.Avalonia

Comment: Yes my code is partially from that demo. For now, until i find out what is causing this issue,  I circumvented it by directly passing the bitmap data on to my MainViewModel. That way i don't need to process the byte[]. Thanks for the assistance.